# Can I use variables in CSS?

Tags: css, variables

I was wondering if it is possible to define css properties as variables. 
For example, can I do something like:

```
<div class="wide(20)"></div>
```

and in .css:

```
.wide(x)
{
width : x% ;
}

.tr-speed(y)
{
-webkit-transition: y s;
}
```

I know this could probably be done with JavaScript but I would like a full CSS solution, if any.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There're several CSS preprocessors with such feature but, of course, none of them is implemented in pure CSS.

Comment: Take a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), they are server (or client) side solutions that support variables and other features.

Answer (score 2):

[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is a very powerful language that compiles to CSS.

It is just CSS syntax with things like variables and functions. 
It is a very popular tool that helps you write DRY CSS.

http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Sass isn't a framework, it's only a preprocessor with a base library of useful functions.  Compass is a framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new W3C draft for CSS variables.

Have a look at:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/

Maybe there will be a support by major browsers, soon:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Mozilla Firefox Nightly is able to read those CSS variables. For all other browsers, there is a polyfill: http://www.myth.io/